# How notepad++ find function works?

Tags: java

For a given larger string which contains random numbers and for that individual numbers how can I find count of each number?

My Approach:

1. Starting from first number finding count of that number and store that number parallel into another array/string.
2. For second number first search in parallel array whether that is present if not than find count in main string.
3. Continue.

Is there any other faster and efficient way of doing this, because I am using notepad/notepad++ find function which works pretty fast compared to my method.

Code:

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> subList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    int count=1;
    int number=list.get(i);

    if(!subList.contains(number)){
        for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){               
            if(list.get(j)==number){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(number+" "+count);
        subList.add(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't write your application in Java, is usually a pretty sure fire way of getting it very quick. That and employ a clever way of storing the data.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It's kind of hard to understand.  An example would be nice.

Comment: Have you written any code, pseudo or otherwise, to demonstrate what you're thinking?

Comment: Mark Nelson has a decent article on [suffix trees](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/) using [Ukkonen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm).

Comment: can you show *your method*

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have a demonstration of what you have, we can better analyze the situation.

It looks like you're not sure how to associate the count with each individual element. You're incrementing a count, but it's not associated with any of the items, and probably the biggest confusion factor.

This is where something like a HashMap works well.

In this case, you want to associate a number you've found, i, with its own personal count, c. The count will start at 1, for the first we've found, and then increment as we find more. With the HashMap idea, we can take any integer you can think of and use that as a key, and then associate its count c as the value you fetch from the key.

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> findMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int number = list.get(i);

        if (findMap.get(number) == null) {
            // we didn't find it in the map, so we put it in with a counter of 1
            findMap.put(number, 1);
        }
        else {
            // we already have inserted it, we should add 1 to counter
            findMap.put(number, findMap.get(number) + 1);
        }
    }

    //to get everything out of the HashMap
    for (Integer i : findMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + findMap.get(i));
    }
```

As a task for the OP if you have enough experience, determine Big O of the insertion portion of the code.